# Move tables from one postgres db to another using nifi

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

I'm new using nifi -
i'm trying to create a simple flow where i just copy a table from one db in postgres to another.
the postgres is on my local machine.

I've tried using QueryDataBase processor and PutDataBaseRecord, also GenerateTableFetch.
I see that I do get the to the source table, but the target table (i created it in advanced) is not being filled with the data.

I'm not sure how to debug this, I tried to ask ChatGPT
he also offered to convert the data type, but still, the flow seems to run but the data is not in the target table.

Can anyone please help me? i believe it should be that hard.
What processor I need? what to pay attention? how can i know where is the problem?

PutDatabaseRecord processor
QueryDatabaseTable processor
JdbcRecordSetWriter processor (chatGPT said, don't see something like this)